# how to generate a soap request envelope from wsdl in java without using third party jars and wsimport?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I have taken a sample WSDL http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL. I am trying to find a way to generate a soap request envelope for an operation present in that WSDL through JAVA without using WSImport and third party jars. Is there any way to do this?